# Custom orderBy in AngularJS without absolute string comparison?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm building a small CSS beautifier for my system, which will only build when the CSS is in a particular order.
The idea is to dump CSS into a textarea, and for the app to generate an ordered version of the code.
I managed to do it, but only if the code pasted in the textarea has no properties.

For example:

```
content
margin
font-size
```

Will work.

But if it's proper code with properties:

```
content: 'test';
margin: 10px;
font-size: 1em;
```

Then it won't.

I think that what is failing is that the comparative function will only consider the string as a full, not as a partial.

Here's the comparative function and [a JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/cirepapevo/edit?html,js,output).

```
$scope.customOrder = function (item) {
  switch (item) {
    case 'display':
        return 1;
    case 'flex':
        return 2;
    case 'flex-basis':
        return 3;
    case 'flex-direction':
        return 4;
    ... 
  }
};
```

Any ideas on how to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `switch`, parse the attribute name, like so:

```
$scope.customOrder = function (item) {
   var parsedItem = item.substr(0, item.indexOf(':'));
   switch (parsedItem) {
     case 'display':
       return 1;
      case 'flex':
        return 2;
      ...
```